# iOS 8 - UIBarButtonItem Push Segue overriding Action

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, segue, uibarbuttonitem

This issue seems to be new with iOS 8, as I had this setup working in iOS 7 and it just started causing problems when I updated.

In Interface Builder, if I have a `UIBarButtonItem` that triggers a Show (Push) segue to another View Controller and is also connected to an action, the segue happens but the action is never called. If I try this with a regular button, both the segue and action are called. This happens with `UIBarButtonItem`s both when they are in the Navigation Bar and in a standalone `UIToolBar`

Could anyone explain why this might be happening/offer a possible fix? Thanks

Comment: Can you explain why you need both an action and a segue to be called from the same touch event?

Comment: @MikeTaverne A very common reason would be to prepate data for the presented view controller.

Comment: In my situation, I'm recording audio and need to send a stop message to the RecordingController before the segue happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A fix would be to create a manual segue and call it from your action using `-(void)performSegueWithIdentifier: sender:`

Answer (score 1):

I think the preferred way to do this is to implement prepareForSegue in your view controller:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!) {
if (segue.identifier == "MySegueIdentifier") {
    // pass data to next view
}
}
```

Where "MySegueIdentifier" is the name of the segue in your storyboard.